# Osmotic Pressure of Aqueous Solution

Tags: equilibrium, aqueous-solution, solutions, pressure

The osmotic pressure of an aqueous solution at $25$ Celsius is $92.0$ $kPa$. Calculate the boiling point
of the solution. (Assume that the density of the solution is $1.0$ $g/mL$, ignore the mass of the
solute)

Using the formula $\pi = cRT = \rho g h$, we can find the concentration value and height; however, how one should proceed to evaluate the boiling point using the ebullioscopic constant and morality of the solution? Are there any suggested ideas for solving it, considering all the givens are outlined in the statement?

Comment: Are there any ideas except for the formula $\pi = cRT$

Comment: Is there any information about the molar mass or molecular formula of the compound?

Comment: No, unfortunately. That was the part where I was stuck basically. No additional information is given.

Comment: @M.L In fact, according to the statement, it has been mentioned that the mass of the solute should be ignored. And regarding the molar mass, I guess we can find it using the $\pi = MRT$ formula. What do you think?

Comment: I edited the problem statement; would be appreciated if anyone could suggest further ideas!

Comment: Some solutions are very amoral.  ( *morality of the solution* )

Comment: One of the first ideas coming to mind is searching. As it is very simple topic described on internet or in textbooks many times on many places.

Comment: @Poutnik I had already searched before posting this question here. So, be sure that such problems are not anywhere!

Comment: Not sure what the problem is--you can calculate the solute concentration from the osmotic pressure. Then you can calculate the boiling point elevation from the concentration. You don't need the molar mass, since osmotic pressure and boiling point elevation both (to first order) depend only on conentration.

Comment: @Snowflake Relations osmotic pressure->concentration and concentration+density+E.c->boiling point shift ARE nearly anywhere. The given density 1 g/mL and omitting solute mass is great help. You can consider in this special case numerical equality of molarity and molality.